# rosserial with 2 arduino

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi every one. I have a problem when interfacing raspberry pi with two arduino through rosserial_python, when I connect to the second arduino after the first one succeeded,the first terminal will say : `**shutdown request: new node registered with same name**`
i search  and find the solution like include parameter _name after the rosrun command, but it's not worked for me.please help me. thank you and sorry for my english

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341353/rosserial-with-2-arduino/) by [drtritm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50806/drtritm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2020-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot have 2 or more nodes with the same name.  So you need to change the name of one of your rosserial nodes, eg:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py __name:="node2" ... etc
```

Note the double underscore preceding name.

Or, as suggested, using a launch file:

```
<launch>
<!-- Launch 2 Arduino boards -->

    <node
        pkg="rosserial_python"
        type="serial_node.py"
        name="ArduinoOne"
        args="/dev/ttyACM0"
    ></node>

    <node
        pkg="rosserial_python"
        type="serial_node.py"
        name="ArduinoTwo"
        args="/dev/ttyACM1"
    ></node>
</launch>
```

The above requires the Arduino boards to be /dev/ttyACM0 and /dev/ttyACM1.  This can be avoided by using [udev rules](https://clearpathrobotics.com/blog/2015/01/udev/) to give each board a unique symbolic name, eg:

```
<launch>
<!-- Launch the Arduino Board with Adafruit 9-DOF IMU -->

<node
    pkg="rosserial_python"
    type="serial_node.py"
    name="arduino_imu_9dof"
    args="/dev/elegooOne"
    respawn="true"
></node>
    
</launch>
```

So above we've given the Arduino board the symbolic name elegooOne.  Larger Arduino boards, eg Uno, Mega, have a unique serial number that's good for udev rules.

---

Originally posted by [Marvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/32593/marvin/) with karma: 91 on 2020-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drtritm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50806/drtritm/) on 2020-01-12**:
Yes, i did it like i mentioned in the question, and it's not worked

**Comment by [Marvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/32593/marvin/) on 2020-01-14**:
When using rosrun try using the name argument with a double underscore to rename.  Obviously, you can check, one at a time, that the nodes are being renamed as expected via rosnode list.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-14**:
I would suggest to use a launch file instead. It's easier to edit, easier to start and was intended to be used to start multiple ROS nodes.

**Comment by [drtritm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50806/drtritm/) on 2020-01-17**:
thanks very much